# resize form in code to hide hidden items

Tags: c#

i have a program i  made that can pead replays from a game then get data out of them i am trying to add support for tag replays so i need 2 more list boxes and 4 more buttons on the form but i want them hidden when they aren't being used(when a tag replay isnt opened) i have tried autosize with a minimal and maximal width-height and it didnt work dont know what else to try oh and im using a table layout panel to organize everything

heres some shots to show what i want

[image][image]

Comment: Pictures may say a thousand words, but here code is just as important =)

Comment: I may be missing something but why not just set the `Visible` property to false?

Comment: there no point adding code as there is no code for what i wanna do the only code i could post is the decryption code of the lzma replays which works fine

Comment: i did set the visible property to false but that leaves a blank space on the form as shown above

Comment: @outlaw1994, where is your code that hides out the controls?

Comment: i just set the visible property to false there is no code though i could use code like listbox1.visible = false; but i prefer not to

Comment: Just set the height of the form itself alongside the code that hides out the controls.

Comment: i tried that and it resizes all my other controls an doesnt get rid of the space :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started.

Your controls resize with the form because the table layout is anchored to the form from the bottom.
So, what I just tried and could work for you is to temporarily turn off the bottom anchor, change the form height, then bring back the bottom anchor as it was.

Since you haven't shared any code, I'm using typical control names:

```
var oldanchor = tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor;  // memorize the old anchor
tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top;  // reset anchor
this.Height = 200;  // change the form's height
tableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = oldanchor;  // bring back the old anchor
```

Comment: you are awesome my man i have never even heard of anchors but this works perfectly you can be sure im gonna study up on them now i wish i could upvote you more than once

Comment: thanks to your help i finished it and was able to release a beta for the program you can view it here if you want http://www.ygopro.co/tabid/95/g/posts/m/34512/YgoPro-Replay-Deck-Extractor.aspx

Comment: Good for you! Looks good, mate ;) Makes me glad you think I've helped with your release.